# Complex Analysis: Theorem Name

Tags: complex-analysis

In my textbook the following theorem is designated "Proposition 3.4.2 part (vi)".  There are 6 parts total in the overall theorem.  I'll just type the part I'm interested in below.  My question is, is there a more standard name for this theorem?  I would like to find an additional introduction to it if possible.

Let $f$ be meromorphic on the open connected set $\Omega\subseteq \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ and let $A$ be the set of its poles in $\Omega$.  Then:

(a)  $A$ is a countable set.

(b)  The accumulation points of $A$ are on the boundary of $\Omega$.

(c)  The set $\Omega \setminus A$ is open.

(d)  If $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$, then $A\cap K$ is a finite set.